# ggplot - two legend boxes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb, gear, am) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, color = as.factor(gear), linetype = as.factor(am), group = interaction(gear, am)))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))
```

Produces the following image:

[image]

However, I would like the color legend and the linetype legend to be in separate legend boxes. I made the desired output in Paint and I am wondering how to achieve this via ggplot:

[image]

Comment: Try `legend.background`. This gives you boxes around each legend but the size of the box depends on the content e.g. the length of the legend title and key labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate legend boxes can be achieved by using `legend.background` instead of `legend.background.box`. This gives you boxes around each legend but the size of the box depends on the content e.g. the length of the legend title and key labels. To get boxes of equal width you can add some spaces to the legend title via e.g. `stringr::str_pad` to get titles of equal width. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb, gear, am) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, color = as.factor(gear), linetype = as.factor(am), group = interaction(gear, am)))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  labs(linetype = stringr::str_pad("as.factor(am)", 15), color = stringr::str_pad("as.factor(gear)", 15)) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'carb', 'gear' (override with `.groups` argument)
```

[image]